# Spring Data elasticsearch @Query annotation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My JSON doc is like this:
Meu documento JSON é assim:

```
{
"query" : {
    "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "should": [
        {
          "bool":   { "must": [{"match": {"txt": "p"}},
                    {"match": {"nm": "p"}}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": { "must": [{"match": {"txt": "p"}}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": { "must": [{"match": {"nm": "p"}}
            ]
          }
        }
        ]
        }
},
"highlight": {
    "number_of_fragments" : 1,
    "order": "score",
    "boundary_scanner": "sentence", 
    "fragment_size" : 300,
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "fragmenter": "span", 
    "fields" : {
        "nm": {},
        "txt": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

How should I write the query method using @Query annotation ? (or if there is any other method that I can put the highlight) ?
Como devo escrever o método de consulta usando a anotação @Query? (ou se houver algum outro método que eu consiga colocar o highlight) ?

observation:highlight it's very important
observação:destaque que é muito importante

Thanks for any suggestion.
Obrigado por qualquer sugestão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the query part into the `@Query` annotation, see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/repositories/elasticsearch-repository-queries.html#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query).

For the highlight definition, you can use the `@Highlight` annotation, check [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/repositories/elasticsearch-repositories.html#elasticsearch.repositories.annotations.highlight)